# ADO.NET: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, casting

I get a specified cast not valid error when I execute a stored proc like this:

```
return (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

When I execute it in SQL Server it returns 1, so I know my proc is working.

What is wrong with my cast?

Updated:

```
    public static int IsPresent(string userName, int inTime)
    {
        SqlConnection connObj = new SqlConnection();
        connObj.ConnectionString = Util.SQLConct();
        connObj.Open();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("usp_IsUserLocked", connObj);

        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", userName));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InTime", inTime));

        return (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ToInt32()`?

Comment: can you post the command text?

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the type. Does the SP really return a value or is it just the rowcount?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it returns 1 or 0 depending on if user is present or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that your method returns double or int64 or any other type which cannot be implicitly casted to (int). Use `Convert.ToInt32` to ensure that your method returns the right type.

```
using System;

...
return Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: I get an error: The name 'Convert' does not exist in current context

Comment: user793468: make sure you include System namespace